# how to integrate qunits with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, qunit

we are using Qunits to write testcases,Test cases are getting passed,we are using Jenkins for continuous integration.can any one please let us know how to inegrate qunits with jenkins .so that Jenkins picks up tests and runs the testcases

result.xml format
[image]

Comment: A simple google search returns this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482493/qunit-jscoverage-jenkins

Comment: Thanks for responding Slav.I am facing one issue.i am running qunit testcases by ant build.xml,test cases are getting passed but it is failing to log the results to output xml file.the file consisting only <testsuites name="testsuites">
</testsuites>

Comment: When you run your `build.xml` manually, does the output xml file get generated then? Does it have a relative location or absolute?

Comment: I modified qunit library..now the results are written to xml file.sample format i have updated in the above question.I am not sure this is the exact o/p jenkins will able to read it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does qunit-reporter-junit generate junit compatible xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686411/does-qunit-reporter-junit-generate-junit-compatible-xml)