# not able to write the qunit test results to output xml using build.xml

Tags: ant, phantomjs, qunit

I am using build.xml with phantom.js to execute the qunit testcases,test are passing but the results are not getting written to output xml file.qunit.done function of qunit.runner.js gives

Cannot write junit results file error  in QUnit.done  function.

any one has any idea/suggestion

thanks in advance

Comment: First of all welcome to stackoverflow. Secondly please don't ask a variation on the same question multiple times. Far better to expand your original question, otherwise you'll get downvoted and ignored. Thirdly have you checked obvious things like the ownership and permissions of directories and files? This is the the most common explanation for this kind of error. Lastly if you're running the process from Jenkins, it would be running as another user. Hope this helps.

Comment: Appears related to this Jenkins question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214983/how-to-integrate-qunits-with-jenkins

Comment: Thanks Mark for the suggestions.But when i asked multiple questions on the same issue in one  of my earlier questions they asked me to raise new request for them.coming to file permissions,i am trying to write results to a file with in the project  work space..does it effects?

Comment: I don't know.... Have you checked both the ownership and permissions of the project workspace? What OS are you running on? There are quite a few variables going on here. This is why you are best advised to ask one question, clarify it if necessary and accept an answer before moving on.

Comment: file permissions and ownership  are fine.I am using windows7